# Access a Delegate out of a Model

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, delegates, qtreeview, qcombobox

I'm using a QTreeView which has an own model for drawing icons, showing texts and other things more.

Next for some cells of this tree I have added a QComboBox via a delegate which works fine.

Now my problem: when the user selects a value from the QComboBox, this newly selected value is not shown in the cell afterwards, it is empty. From what I understand this happens because the model has to return the current value out of data() -> Qt::DisplayRole. But: how can I access the delegate and the correct QComboBox from my model to get the current value? Or what else is the correct way to display the selected combobx-value in the cell?

Thanks!

Comment: show your delegate code. What kind of model do you sue? Standard? Own? Or some predefined? Note there is also `Qt::EditRole`.

Comment: Do you reimplement QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData?

Comment: @Kirill Chernikov : thanks, that's it :-)